# Could not able to locate the error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I tries to debug an error in IE 8 developer tools. It is showing that the error as follows,

`'length' is null or not an object  JScript - script block, line 21 character 19`

But i could not locate the **script block, line 21 character 19**. So do anybody have any idea on how to locate this error?

Comment: try to comment one js file at time until the error disappear. Then identify lines with `length`. Finally check if the object/s in which the property is applied is/are not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to enable debuging mode my click on start debug, when error occur, IE will locate the block for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It locates the block. But how could we find, in which JS file, that block present.

Comment: When you enable debugging mode (search gogole to find out how), IE will show the file and highlight the line for you